# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to TextView

Tags: android, textview

I do not understand why I am unable to create objects of Buttons or Views with values of xml resources.  I understand that the resources are stored as int, but i believe i have seen others do things such as what is below:

code from MainActivity:

```
TextView [] tViews = new TextView[] {R.id.calcView, R.id.logText};
```

code from R.java

```
public static final int calcView=0x7f080000;
public static final int logText=0x7f080026;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advanced...

Comment: Try something like this `TextView t1 = (TextView) R.id.calcView;`.

Comment: Don't try that.  It won't let you anyway, as the cast will fail to compile, but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those ids are not TextViews.  There may be TextViews with those ids, but the ids are just integers.  You need to do a findViewById on each of those views to get the corresponding text views.

Comment: great thank you that works, but what about buttons?  I end up declaring the buttons as Integers to gain access to them in code, how can i do this the right way?

Comment: Same thing.  You use findViewById to get any view inside of a layout.  I suggest you reread some of the Android tutorials, you obviously missed a few things.

Comment: well thank you for your help, i will look through the tutorials again soon

Comment: @user2204661 To maybe help, not sure of your Java background, but the key here is findViewById will return a View instance, regardless of what type of element is declared in the xml.  All components in an XML UI extend 'View', so you'll need to cast it to whatever type you're expecting (and, in general, only cast to the level of detail you need, so if only onClick, View is fine, but setText needs to be on a TextView).  If this is blowing your mind, you probably need more Java language background.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks bro, no its not blowing my mind, i understand it but android is a little new to me.  I think I was confused because R.id.viewname is just an int reference to a view, and that why it was working for me when i used Integer and not Button....what i was not realizing is to use Button and TextView you must typecast and use the findViewById method to properly return a view to assign the object and value

Thank you everyone